# How do I get a register to store an offset value in at&t syntax?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, att, x86-16

I am using this to write to the video memory (%es = 0xb800):

```
movw $0x074b,%es:(0x0)
```

However, what if I want the offset to be in %ax?

I tried `%es:%ax`, or `%es:(%ax)`, but nothing worked, and I kept getting errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 16 bit mode you are limited in usable address forms. You can't address using `%ax`. The valid forms are:

- optionally one of `bx` or `bp`, plus
- optionally one of `si` or `di`, plus
- optionally a constant displacement

As such, `movw $0x074b, %es:(%di)` would work, for example. See also *Table 2-1. 16-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte* in the official *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 2: Instruction Set Reference, A-Z*

PS: next time show what errors you got.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work now. The error was "bad memory operand".

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to do it right away yesterday, but it was too fast and the system didn't accept it. I'm doing it now.